# Can't login to Skype SDK with non-existing domain name

Tags: javascript, skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I have problem about SigninManager. When I login in with `tan.tastan@abcd.com`, `abdc.com` is a reachable domain. But if I write a wrong domain, for example `tan.tastan@abcd***E***.com`, I am not getting a response and my application is waiting. Nothing happens and there is no return error code.

Here is my sample code, `settings` includes username, password, and domain information.

```
function doLogin(settings) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        window.skypeWebSDKApi.signInManager.signIn(settings).then((response) => {
            resolve(response);
        }, (error) => {
            reject(error);
        }).catch(reject);
    });
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: `what is the problem?` erm ... the domain doesn't exist would be a guess

Comment: by the way, your `doLogin` function is just `function doLogin(settings) {
    return window.skypeWebSDKApi.signInManager.signIn(settings);
}` - if you take away the [promise constructor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: As below, you can see full of my codes. I think, I did all changes what you said. But not working. by the way `settings` parameter has only `userName` and `password`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly what is going on without seeing the contents of `settings` but I suspect you're issue here is a promise not getting resolves. Try simplifying your call:

```js
function doLogin(settings) {
    var app = new api.application;
    app.signInManager.signIn(settings).then(function () {
        console.log('success');
    }, function (error) {
       console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: actually domain name not exist (for example; the correct domain hotmail.com but the user writes hotmaiLL.com) and I am expecting a response with error code. but nothing happens.

Comment: Did you resolve the promise issue? It would explain why you're not getting anything back when the use cancels the auth flow.

Comment: I took away the promise. It did not work. And I refactored the code with alertsignInManager but it did not work too. the error is "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'signIn' of undefined". So is it SDK Bug?

Comment: My apologies, it looks like I fat fingered my snippet there. I've updated the example. The `signinManager` is part of the `application` so I believe the trouble here is that you first need to create the `app` before you can make the call. This would explain the `singIn of undefined`.

Comment: As abow, you can see full of my codes. I think, I did all changes what you said. But not working. by the way `settings` parameter has only `userName` and `password`

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the SDK for quite a while now and this is my experience:
When trying to log in using a non existing domain, the Web SDK **never** returns an error. I've tried different SDK versions and both General Availability and Public Preview API keys.

I ended up starting my own signin timer when trying to sign in.
When no response is received within 20 seconds, I send a signOut request (which cancels the sign in) and show a message to the user (Please make sure you've entered the right username etc..).
It's really lame to have a workaround like this but unfortunately I haven't found a better way yet to deal with this issue, also assuming Microsoft is not going to fix this anymore...